# Check if cursor is inside element's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html

```
<div class='parent'> 
     <div class='child'></div> 
</div>
```

I wanna add a mouseover and mouseout events to `parent` element but, the problem is when the cursor hover `child` elemet it fires mouseout event although it acually still inside `parent` element. 
how I can avoid this to let mouseout event only fires when the cursor leaves `parent` item.

```
$(body).on('mouseover', '.parent' , function(){ /* do somthing */}); 
$(body).on('mouseout',  '.parent' , function(){ /* do another somthing */});
```

Comment: can you add your css code? add display block in parent and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` which will solve your problem.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.parent' , function(){
    console.log("Mouse Enter");
}); 
$(document).on('mouseleave',  '.parent' , function(){ 
        console.log("Mouse Leave");
});
```

Do not use `stopPropagation()` because [The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ga1kvexm/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the [**propagation**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) of the `event` on the child:

```
$(body).on('mouseover', '.child' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}); 
$(body).on('mouseout',  '.child' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseenter/mouseleave events instead of mouseover/mouseout:

```
$(body).on('mouseenter', '.child' , function(e){

}); 
$(body).on('mouseleave',  '.child' , function(e){

});
```

Comment: There's no difference. The key here is that you're stopping event propagation (which is what my answer does that you seemingly stole).

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I just copied the bad code from you and changed the event names, just forgot to remove the stupid e.stopPropagation calls. Thanks for reminding.